# What is the jQuery key code for Left Shift

Tags: jquery

What's the key code for left shift? When I press left shift do something..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JavaScript you can only detect Shift. You can't differentiate left and right shift. Using jQuery:

```
$("body").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    //do something here
  }
});
```

Comment: Please.. don't use inline-JS as the vanilla JS equivalent of JS+jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from [this page](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx), the browser does not differentiate from left and right shift. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029109/1135019

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know is to ask the user.

So what that means is it not possible with code alone, and not desirable to ask the user.

There is probably a better solution to the problem you think you have.