# Can javascript tell the difference between left and right shift key?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keycode

Mostly this is a sanity check. The key code for both shift keys is 16. Does that mean it is actually impossible to distinguish a left and right shift events in a browser?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In newer browsers supporting `DOM3` you can use `event.location` to check the location.

In [the DOM3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#idl-def-KeyboardEvent), there are 4 constants defined for location, `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD`, `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT`, `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT`,  and`DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD`.

In this case, you can do:

```
if (event.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT){

} else if (event.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT){

}
```

Comment: Can you show me the full code? I didn't get how to execute it

Comment: You would have this inside an keyboard event handler in the browser, where the first argument to the event handler function is `event`.

Comment: Its ok. I did it another way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320597/detect-left-or-right-shift-key-in-keypress-jquery/40320730?noredirect=1

Comment: This answer is still valid, but over the years there is a new good answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `event.code` (the physical keyboard string) instead of `event.key` (the numeric ascii value).

[`event.code` MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

> The KeyboardEvent.code property represents a physical key on the keyboard (as opposed to the character generated by pressing the key).

If you scroll down to "Code values" at the  bottom, you can find the two distinct shift keys:

`"ShiftLeft"`, `"ShiftRight"`

Answer (score 2):

Internet explorer is capable of distinguishing left and right shift with the shiftLeft property:

[shiftLeft property (event)](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgjxtkf.php)

Otherwise, they are indistinguishable.

Comment: There are some difference.  Check the example on plunkr in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218752/how-to-detect-shift-right-arrow-some-other-key-in-angular

The same code works fine with left shift and does not work with right shift

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("html").keydown(function(e) {

      if (e.shiftKey) {
         if (event.location == 1) console.log('left shift');
         if (event.location == 2) console.log('right shift');
      }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: You have to click the inside white space when you run code snippet to activate keyboard keys. This is tested in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: This works in Firefox, but in Chrome 92 and above (the ones I tested) it always says "left shift".