# Detect left of right Shift key in keyboard - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keycode

I'm using the below code to check whether the user have pressed the 'shift' key. It returns 16 correctly, since its the keycode for 'shift'.

But is there any way we can detect whether the pressed shift is the **left** or **right** one in the keyboard?

Here is the code I've used:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
        alert(e.which + " or Shift was pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check out this thread for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029033/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-left-and-right-shift-key

Comment: @EricWiener That's great! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `JQuery` in particular, if you just look at your event `e` you will find

`e.originalEvent.code`

Which contains `shiftLeft` or `shiftRight` depending.

I'd guess `originalEvent` is actually the base javascript keypress event you could get from something like

`body.onkeydown = function (e) { console.log(e); }`

since it looks identical.