# Detect Left or Right Shift Key in keypress - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a web app where user have to enter capital letters. I have restrict them to use right shift key for some key like a,s,d,f and left shift key for h,j,k,l (basically to detect whether the user is using the correct shift key for capital letters)

The below JQuery code helps to find which key is pressed, including numbers, small and capital letters. But it doesn't tell me whether he have used left/right shift key for capital letters

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
});
```

After a lot of searching I found a code to check **detect left/right shift key**

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
 var key = e.key + e.location;
 if(key == "Shift1")
   alert('Left shift key');
 if(key == "Shift2")
   alert('Right shift key');
});
```

How can i modify the JQuery script so that whenever a capital letter is pressed, I can check whether he pressed using left or right shift key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a little help from @Micheal Nakayama, I did it myself. Here is the code:

```
<script>
var shiftLeft
var shiftRight
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  var key = e.key + e.location;
  if(key=="Shift1")
  {
    shiftLeft = 1
  }
  else if(key=="Shift2")
  {
    shiftRight = 1
  }
  else if(shiftLeft==1)
  {
    console.log("Left+"+e.key)
  }
  else if(shiftRight==1)
  {
    console.log("Right+"+e.key)
  }
  else {
    console.log(e.key)
  }
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  var key = e.key + e.location;
  if(key=="Shift1")
  {
    shiftLeft = 0
  }
  else if(key=="Shift2")
  {
    shiftRight = 0
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if a the key has been pressed down and store the pressed keys in an associative array and check if they are true when other keys are pressed, so:

```
var pressedKeys = [];
var shift1Keys = []; //array of keys that are valid for shift1;
var shift2Keys = []; //array of keys that are valid for shift2;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    var key = e.key + e.location;

    if(key === "Shift1") {
        pressedKeys['shift1'] = true;
    } else if(key === "Shift2") {
        pressedKeys['shift2'] = true;
    } else {
        pressedKeys[key] = true;

        if(pressedKeys['shift1'] && shift1keys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            alert('shift1 and key pressed');
        } else if (pressedKeys['shift2'] && shift2keys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            alert('shift2 and key pressed');
        }
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    var key = e.key + e.location;

    if(key == "Shift1") {
        pressedKeys['shift1'] = false;
    } else if(key == "Shift2") {
        pressedKeys['shift2'] = false;
    } else {
        pressedKeys[key] = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Its not perfect code. Its meant to give you a direction to go.

Comment: I have no idea why you are doing key = e.key + e.location, its up to you to figure out what the little things wrong are because I don't have your code or your goals.

Comment: ok. I'm building it now, with the logic you have given me. Working on it

Comment: best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions here do not cover the edge case of both shift keys being held, which may not behave as you expect.

From the perspective of the browser,

- the second shift key to be held wins repeated keydowns
- the second shift key to be released wins the keyup

This means to match the behaviour you should discard previous locations on each location down, here is an example of such an implementation which only logs when keys are used along side <kbd>Shift</kbd>

```
function tellMeWhere(type, e, meta) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        console.log(e.key, type + '\'d', 'with Shift', meta.Shift)
    }
}

(function (callback) {
    var metaKeyList = ['Alt', 'Control', 'Meta', 'Shift'],
        metaKeys = {};
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (metaKeyList.indexOf(e.key) !== -1) {
            metaKeys[e.key] = e.location;
        } else {
            callback('down', e, Object.assign({}, metaKeys));
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (metaKeyList.indexOf(e.key) === -1) {
            callback('press', e, Object.assign({}, metaKeys));
        }
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        if (metaKeyList.indexOf(e.key) !== -1) {
            delete metaKeys[e.key];
        } else {
            callback('up', e, Object.assign({}, metaKeys));
        }
    });
}(tellMeWhere));
```

Then say you typed <kbd>Left Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, the above would log

```
A down'd with Shift 1
A press'd with Shift 1
A up'd with Shift 1
```

Then say you typed <kbd>Right Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, the above would log

```
Z down'd with Shift 2
Z press'd with Shift 2
Z up'd with Shift 2
```